# jhipster and master detail

Tags: angular, spring, typescript, jhipster, master-detail

I have created all my classes with Jhipster .jdl file.
Now I have 2 classes with master detail relation so I see the master record (for example A) in top of my form, and a list/table of details record (for example B).
Note that even class B was generated by jhipster!

Now in my list/table representation of B I need to put the delete button so I link it to a function copying from the original DetailBClass:

```
...in the html file...
<button type="button" (click)="deleteDetail(detailB)" [pTooltip]="'entity.action.delete' | translate" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
       <fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
</button>
...in the ts file...
deleteDetail(detailBClass: IDetailBClass) {
   const modalRef = this.modalService.open(DetailBClassDeleteDialogComponent, { size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' });
   modalRef.componentInstance.detailBClass = detailBClass;
}
```

Doing this, when I click over the delete-row button, give an error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type DetailBClassDeleteDialogComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: MasterAClassModule and DetailBClassModule!
Please consider moving DetailBClassDeleteDialogComponent to a higher module that imports MasterAClassModule and DetailBClassModule. 
You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes DetailBClassDeleteDialogComponent then import that NgModule in MasterAClassModule and DetailBClassModule.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to copy and paste the module (not sharing between pages) and use this copy in the detail.